# Can Tesseract OCR recognize images with less than 4 characters?

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

I'm taking a PDF and cutting it up into 400+ sections and feeding those individual sections to Tesseract. Which is working perfectly. Except for fields that have 1, 2, or 3 characters. If it have 4 or more, or Tesseract believes there's 4 or more, it works fine.

I'm using the C# wrapper by CharlesW on [GitHub](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract).

Comment: Have you tried to play with its 11 different PageSegMode?

Comment: @nguyenq Thanks! Changing the PageSegMode helped fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nguyenq suggested, changing the PageSegMode fixed the issue. The [wrapper](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract) I'm using has a property called `.DefaultPageSegMode` that allowed me to fix the issue.